# Excel: adding hyperlink in a cell with existing text

Tags: excel, hyperlink

In Excel I have a cell filled with text and I just want to insert a hyperlink (same as in MS Word) but the hyperlink-insert-icon (or CTRL+K) does not work.

Assume (as an example) I have the following text already in a cell: "For more help please visit here."

I want to add a hyperlink to/under the word "here", so when you click at "here" the hyperlink will be opened.

Comment: ...........not currently possible in an Excel cell....the link would be "hot" for the entire cell.